# How to display related data from MySQL with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables on my MySQL Database: 'Jobs' and 'Categories'. In the 'Jobs' table, I have relation 'Category' to table 'Categories', this relation contains ID of the category of job. So basically, in the database it works perfectly.

Now I need to display all jobs on one PHP page, everything is going alright, but when it displays job's category, I see just ID of the category, no the name of it. Please, help me, there're queries I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM jobs LEFT JOIN categories ON jobs.category=categories.id
SELECT jobs, categories FROM jobs LEFT JOIN categories ON jobs.category=categories.id

( [job_id] => 1 [category] => 1 [name] => Programmer [desc] => Description of programmer [date] => 20.09.2018 [aviable] => 1 [category_id] => [category_name] => )
```

Comment: Why doesn't `SELECT * FROM jobs LEFT JOIN categories ON jobs.category=categories.id` work?

Comment: @Nick hi, I don't know why, but it displays IDs again

Comment: But it should display all the fields from `jobs` and `categories`, which would include `categories.name`... Can you show the output of that query in your question? use the edit link under the tags

Comment: `SELECT * FROM jobs LEFT JOIN categories ON jobs.category=categories.id` This should work you can acces the data rom the categories through: `categories.id` or `categories.name` etc. To see all the data you have access too just use `var_dump($sqlresult);`

Comment: It gives your question context if you offer some sample data and your table schemas with your question.  Even better is an instantly usable demo link from sqlfiddle.com or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have posted the PHP code you are using in to display data. Nevertheless, here are two possible solutions to your problem.

You are calling all the columns in both tables so I am assuming you're calling the category_id instead of the name. To whatever code you are calling the name, try calling the specific category name i.e. $row['category_name'].

The other possible cause is, you might already have a name column in the jobs table. A solution for this scenario is to call the specific rows you need.

example:
Select jobs.id, jobs.name,category.name as category_name

Comment: Thank you, it does work!
I didn't know I need to display data with the name of another table. Thank you a lot and thanks to a everyone who commented on here :)